# Combinar Dataframes de pandas con texto

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

quiero combinar información de DataFrames de una forma muy concreta y no se como hacerlo directamente con pandas. 
Tengo un dataframe con datos para varios experimentos:

```
"accuracy", "precision", "recall", "notprecision", "not recall"
      0.9          0.6        0.4            0.7           0.6
      0.6          0.5        0.4            0.3           0.6
      0.7          0.5        0.5            0.7           0.6
```

y mi intención es agruparlos, para guardarlos en un excel sacando la media y la varianza de cada metrica y además con el formato "precision (notprecision)" "recall (notrecall)", es decir, quedarme con un dataframe final así:

```
"accuracy",              "precision",                 "recall"
      0.75,  0.55+-0.10 (0.50+-0.30),  0.43+-0.10 (0.60+-0.00)
```

Hacer la media y la varianza se, pero combinarlos de esa manera de una forma sencilla, sin tener que ir extrayendo valores uno a uno, juntandolos en un string y volviendo a crear otro DataFrame no. Son varias tablas y quiero hacerlo lo mas eficiente posible. 
Si alguien tiene idea de como hacer, aunque sea la combinación media+-varianza lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente. La verdad que es bastante retorcido, pero no he visto forma más directa.

## Explicación paso a paso

La idea es la siguiente. Partimos de tu tabl, llamémosla `df`, que puede ser como esta:

```
   accuracy  precision  recall  notprecision  not recall
0       0.9        0.6     0.4           0.7         0.6
1       0.6        0.5     0.4           0.3         0.6
2       0.7        0.5     0.5           0.7         0.6
```

Si aplicamos `df.mean()` te hace la media por columnas dando como resultado una Series tal que así:

```
accuracy        0.733333
precision       0.533333
recall          0.433333
notprecision    0.566667
not recall      0.600000
dtype: float64
```

La idea es renombrar los índices para que en vez de "accuracy", etc. se llamen `avg_accuracy`, etc. y a la vez cambiar los espacios por "_" en los nombres de los índices en que aparezcan (como en "`not recall"`). Esto se puede hacer con un `rename` sobre esa serie:

```
>>> df.mean().rename(lambda x: "avg_"+ x.replace(" ", "_"))
avg_accuracy        0.733333
avg_precision       0.533333
avg_recall          0.433333
avg_notprecision    0.566667
avg_not_recall      0.600000
dtype: float64
```

Esta "serie" se puede convertir a un diccionario python sin más que añadir `.to_dict()` al final:

```
>>> df.mean().rename(lambda x: "avg_"+ x.replace(" ", "_")).to_dict()
{'avg_accuracy': 0.7333333333333334,
 'avg_precision': 0.5333333333333333,
 'avg_recall': 0.43333333333333335,
 'avg_notprecision': 0.5666666666666667,
 'avg_not_recall': 0.6}
```

Si hacemos lo propio con `df.std()` podemos tener otro diccionario con las desviaciones típicas. En este segundo caso voy a renombrar las claves para que sean `std_accuracy` etc.:

```
>>> df.std().rename(lambda x: "std_"+ x.replace(" ", "_")).to_dict()
{'std_accuracy': 0.1527525231651947,
 'std_precision': 0.05773502691896256,
 'std_recall': 0.05773502691896257,
 'std_notprecision': 0.23094010767585027,
 'std_not_recall': 0.0}
```

Digamos que el primer diccionario lo guardo en una variable `medias`, y el segundo en otra variable `desviaciones`. Puedo usar esos diccionarios para construir la cadena deseada mediante una "plantilla" y `.format()`, así:

```
(
"{avg_accuracy:.2f},"
"{avg_precision:.2f}±{std_precision:.2f} ({avg_notprecision:.2f}±{std_notprecision:.2f}),"
"{avg_recall:.2f}±{std_recall:.2f} ({avg_not_recall:.2f}±{std_not_recall:.2f})"
.format(**medias, **desviaciones)
)
```

El resultado es una cadena como la siguiente:

```
'0.73,0.53±0.06 (0.57±0.23),0.43±0.06 (0.60±0.00)'
```

que tiene ya la estructura que buscabas, salvo que he separado por comas cada componente, pues mi idea final es crear con todo esto un nuevo csv.

Si repetimos todo lo anterior para cada una de las tablas que tengas, cada tabla quedará reducida al final a una cadena como la que acabo de mostrar. Cada una de estas cadenas será una fila del csv que estamos construyendo. Podemos ir guardando cada una de estas cadenas en una lista, para después hacer `"\n".join()` a esa lista y así obtener en una cadena el CSV que buscábamos.

Esa cadena ya podrías volcarla sin más a disco, si lo que buscabas era un CSV, pero si quieres tenerla en un nuevo dataframe pandas, puedes usar `io.StringIO` para "hacer creer" a pandas que está leyendo de un fichero, cuando en realidad está leyendo de una cadena, y usar su método `pandas.read_csv()`.

## Todo junto

Supongomos que tienes una lista llamada `all_tables`, y que cada elemento de esa lista es un dataframe como el que has mostrado. Entonces:

```
lista = ["accuracy,precision,recall"] # Encabezados del CSV que vamos a crear
for table in all_tables:
    medias = table.mean().rename(lambda x: "avg_"+ x.replace(" ", "_")).to_dict()
    desviaciones = table.std().rename(lambda x: "std_"+ x.replace(" ", "_")).to_dict()
    lista.append(
        "{avg_accuracy:.2f},"
        "{avg_precision:.2f}±{std_precision:.2f} ({avg_notprecision:.2f}±{std_notprecision:.2f}),"
        "{avg_recall:.2f}±{std_recall:.2f} ({avg_not_recall:.2f}±{std_not_recall:.2f})"
        .format(**medias, **desviaciones))
new_csv="\n".join(lista)
```

`new_csv` será una cadena con un formato válido para CSV, conteniendo la información buscada. Puedes "leer" ese csv (sin necesidad de volcarlo a disco) para volver a tener un dataframe, así:

```
import io
tabla_final = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(new_csv))
```

Si vas a usar luego `tabla_final.to_csv()` para generar un archivo válido para Excel, deberás especificar `encoding="utf-8-sig"` como parámetro para que el carácter `±` que he usado en las cadenas no cause problemas. O cambia ese carácter por `+-` si lo prefieres.

**Por ejemplo**, ya que no tengo tus tablas, solo para probar, he hecho `all_tables = [df, df, df]`, es decir, tres veces la misma tabla, por lo que el resultado tendrá tres filas, todas iguales. Y este es el resultado que queda finalmente en la variable `tabla_final`:

```
   accuracy              precision                 recall
0      0.73  0.53±0.06 (0.57±0.23)  0.43±0.06 (0.60±0.00)
1      0.73  0.53±0.06 (0.57±0.23)  0.43±0.06 (0.60±0.00)
2      0.73  0.53±0.06 (0.57±0.23)  0.43±0.06 (0.60±0.00)
```

que, si no he entendido mal, es lo que buscabas.